# Send email works locally, but not from remote server

Tags: c#

I am attending to send email via the following function and while it works fine when I run it from the local server, it fails when I run it remotely. What might be causing this problem?

```
private void SendEmail()
{
    try
    {
        MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com",587);
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = loginInfo;
        NetworkCredential loginInfo = new NetworkCredential("xx@gmail.com", "xxxx");
        message.From = new MailAddress("xx@gmail.com", "xx");
        message.To.Add(new MailAddress("yyy@zzz.ac.in","Mail"));
        message.IsBodyHtml = true ;
        string emailContent = "ICHE 2010 - Abstract Received <br><br>Title: " + Abstract_Title.Text + "<br><br>Author: " + TxtAuthor_FirstName.Text + "_" + TxtAuthor_LastName.Text + "<br><br>Abstract in pdf format attached with this email. <br><br> ICHE2010 Website";
        message.Body = emailContent;
        message.Subject = "ICHE 2010 - Abstract Received";
        string FileName = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "\\AbstractPdfs" + "\\" + abstractBO.AbstractFileNameWithTicks);
        Attachment attachmentpdf = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(FileName);
        message.Attachments.Add(attachmentpdf);
        client.EnableSsl = true;
        client.Send(message);
    }
    catch (SmtpException smtpex)
    {
        throw smtpex;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: LOL, I guess some people think letting the code do that talking works. Sometimes it does, mileage will vary.

Comment: this is hosted website for conference in that iam trin send mail with attachment when tried to run it on local server it was fine .but when i run it on browser it fails. wat may be the reason

Answer (score 1):

May be the firewall is blocking your application from sending email using the port. Or your remote server may not have internet connection. There can be many reasons for this. Please explain more.

Comment: this is hosted website for conference in that iam trin send mail with attachment when tried to run it on local server it was fine .but when i run it on remote through browser it fails. wat may be the reason

Answer (score 0):

You need to check two things:

- From your code, check to see if port 587 is not blocked, or is enabled
- Also try opening port 25, which is the port traditionally used by SMTP

Comment: i don hav much idea about the ports 
plz guide me how to check for the ports

Comment: give me idea about how to check for ports

Comment: Unfortunately *that* is a serverfault.com question. Depends on your system administrator

Comment: can mail be sent under 80 port